# Is it possible to load a WMS aerial photo from a external map into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, aerial-photography

Is it possible to load a WMS based aerial photo (like https://geoinfo.frankfurt.de/luftbild-2018) into QGIS and use it as a background-layer for internal use?

Comment: If it is a public WMS then it will be possible.  You just need to know the service URL

Comment: However as this portal is using Mapbender, I'm guessing it's not going to be a public service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the URL

> `https://geoinfo.frankfurt.de/mapproxy/luftbilder_2018/service?`

**and the signature**.. you can load the WMS tiles into QGIS easily

[image]

Comment: Can you include the signature in your answer as text? It's difficult to obtain from the image. Or did you omit it on purpose?

Comment: It is created on the fly when you visit the site (mapproxy uses it) - it looks like it expires after 24hrs.

Comment: Thx very much. Seems to work!

Comment: you can contact Geo-Service-Center.stadtvermessungsamt@stadt-frankfurt.de they have a open WMS service - Google Chrome chrome://flags/ shows the url